# How to create shaded relief from xyz file?

Tags: open-source-gis, shaded-relief

I have a DEM (xyz format) which I want to apply to a "flat" map texture to create a shaded relief, preferably with software that is available for free.

Answer (score 4):

See [gdaldem](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html), which you can use from a command-prompt:

```
$ gdaldem hillshade dem.xyz hillshade.tif
```

There are also a few other interesting modes with the utility that are worth exploring.

Answer (score 2):

[QGIS](http://qgis.org/) and [GRASS](http://grass.osgeo.org/) !

See [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3807).

Comment: Thanks for providing these details. However I did not work with these programs yet and they seem to be pretty complex. Do you have and hints for the workflow I have to use? Especially: How do QGIS and GRASS work together and how can I add my texture layer to be shaded?

Answer (score 1):

[Saga GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html) is worth a look.  It is reasonably intuitive and has a GUI and is free.  There is a good gentle introduction [here](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/saga-gis/SagaManual.pdf), which I found instrumental in getting up to speed nice and quickly.

The modules that would be of particular interest (in version 2.0.8) would be:

- Import/Export - Grids - Import Grid from XYZ
- Terrain Analysis - Lighting, Visibility - Analytical Hillshading
- Import/Export - Images - Export Image (bmp,jpg,pcs,png,tif)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the mentioned GIS Software Tools I'd like to add uDig in combination with jgrasstools ([Spatial Toolbox](http://code.google.com/p/jgrasstools/wiki/JGrassTools4udig)):

[image: uDig Spatial Toolbox Screenshot]

Hope that helps